# React map not rendering

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm having trouble getting my Google Maps rendered on the screen.
I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721416/google-map-is-not-rendering-in-react-app) but even doing so hasn't solved my problem.

What I have:

```
import React from 'react'
import GoogleMap from 'google-map-react';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles'
import s from './CarMap.css'

class MoobieMap extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={s.map}>
            <GoogleMap apiKey={API_KEY} center={{lat: -23.5925282, long: -46.6891377}} zoom={3}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(s)(MoobieMap)
```

And:

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../../components/Layout'
import MoobieMap from './CarMap'

const title = 'Mapa de carros'

export default {

  path: '/car-map',

  async action() {
    return {
      title,
      chunk: 'component',
      component: <Layout title={title}><MoobieMap /></Layout>,
    }
  },

}
```

And the css:

```
.map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

I'm also using the React starter kit.
My DOM looks like this:[image]

I also have no js error in my console.

What am I missing here ?
Thanks!!!

**EDIT:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to import only the css wihtout naming them like :

```
import React from 'react'
import GoogleMap from 'google-map-react';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles'
import './CarMap.css'

class MoobieMap extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <GoogleMap apiKey={API_KEY} center={{lat: -23.5925282, long: -46.6891377}} zoom={3} className="map"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(s)(MoobieMap)
```

What's this (s) between the connect of MoobieMap and withstyles?

I hope it helps and please tell me that your `.map` there's width and height declared...

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't solve the problem. The withStyle apply my css file (CarMap.css) into the component, it is working, as seen on the DOM itself, the style is applied. Also, I've posted the map snippet above

Comment: @Leonardo I'm seeing 100% of height and 100% of width, but relative to what? Where is the inheritance from parent? try to put some fixed values just to check.

Comment: I tried that also, but no luck... I edited with another print ! Thanks again